# How to get the set of OWLIndividual with the same object property assertion?

Tags: java, semantic-web, owl, protege, owl-api

I have an ontology, created using Protegé 4.3.0, and I would use the reasoner in order to retrieve the `OWLIndividual` individuals with the same object property assertion.

I read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695956/retrieve-owl-individuals-with-same-object-properties-using-owl-api-4-0), but I guess I should adapt the proposed solution, because my problem is slightly different, as explained below.

- The ontology contains a set of individuals (*Mouse*, *Cat*, *Dog*) which represent a certain kind of animal.
- The ontology contains a set of individuals (*mouseEyes*, *mouseEars*, *mouseLegs*, *catEyes*, *catEars*, *catLegs*, *dogEyes*, *dogEars*, *dogLegs*) which are associated to different classes (*Eyes*, *Ears*, *Legs*).

  - The individuals *mouseEyes*, *catEyes* and *dogEyes* are associated to the class *Eyes*.
  - The individuals *mouseEars*, *catEars* and *dogEars* are associated to the class *Ears*.
  - The individuals *mouseLegs*, *catLegs* and *dogLegs* are associated to the class *Legs*.
- For esample, the individual *catEyes* has the object property assertion **arePartOf**, which associates *catEyes* and *Cat*. The relationships between the other individuals are similar to this.

Given a specified individual among *mouseEyes*, *mouseEars*, *mouseLegs*, *catEyes*, *catEars*, *catLegs*, *dogEyes*, *dogEars*, *dogLegs*, I would retrieve the set of individuals with the same object property assertion. For esample, if the specified individual is *catEyes*, then the reasoner should retrieve *catEyes*, *catEars*, *catLegs*.

How could I use the reasoner to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't follow why you need a reasoner to accomplish this. Or rather what is the reason you need a reasoner to accomplish this task? You would probably be better of using an ontology code framework like Owl API or Apache Jena and writing a program to handle this task.

Comment: @KunalKhaladkar: I thought I was use a reasoner to have a more compact code.

Comment: Well a reasoner is used for inferring logical consequences from the given facts, in this case your ontology is your fact base. Your task looks like its geared towards querying the model, not inference, and hence my suggestion to use some sort of framework and a program you would write. Also do note that a "reasoner" and a framework like OWL API and Jena are two separate concepts, reasoners are applied to ontologies in these frameworks. Reasoners are not frameworks themselves

Comment: @KunalKhaladkar: Well, so this case does not require a reasoner... However my intent was to use the reasoner [StructuralReasoner](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/reasoner/structural/StructuralReasoner.html) integrated in OWL API...

Comment: Well there's no reason not to use a reasoner, its only that the reasoner does not handle these kinds of querying tasks. Look into sparql here (http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-overview/), its a better way to query your model and keep the code relatively compact :)

Comment: Are you after the matching parts of the same `Cat` instance, or any part that is in relation with a `Cat`?

Comment: I found that the method `getObjectPropertyValues` in [`OWLReasoner`](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/reasoner/OWLReasoner.html) was useful in solving the problem exposed in the question using the reasoner, so I posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the method `getObjectPropertyValues` in [`OWLReasoner`](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/reasoner/OWLReasoner.html) was useful in solving the problem exposed in the question using the reasoner. As pointed in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255921/how-to-get-the-set-of-owlindividual-with-the-same-object-property-assertion?noredirect=1#comment52413622_32255921), it is true that SPARQL would be a better way to query the model.

The following is the solution I implemented using the reasoner.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLNamedIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectPropertyExpression;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyID;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.PrefixManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.InferenceType;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasoner;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasonerFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.structural.StructuralReasonerFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.DefaultPrefixManager;


public class Fauna {
    private final static OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    private final static OWLDataFactory df = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
    private final static OWLReasonerFactory rf = new StructuralReasonerFactory();

    private final OWLOntology ontology;
    private final OWLOntologyID id;
    private final IRI iri;
    private final PrefixManager pm;

    private final OWLReasoner reasoner;

    private final OWLObjectPropertyExpression arePartsOf;
    private final TreeSet<OWLClass> clsParts = new TreeSet<>();

    /**
     * 
     * @param file
     * @throws OWLOntologyCreationException
     */
    public Fauna(File file) throws OWLOntologyCreationException {
        ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
        id = ontology.getOntologyID();
        iri = id.getOntologyIRI();
        pm = new DefaultPrefixManager(iri.toString().concat("#"));

        reasoner = rf.createReasoner(ontology);
        reasoner.precomputeInferences(InferenceType.OBJECT_PROPERTY_ASSERTIONS);

        arePartsOf = df.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create(iri + "#arePartsOf"));

        for (String s : new String[] { "Eyes", "Ears", "Legs" }) {
            OWLClass cls = df.getOWLClass(":" + s, pm);
            clsParts.add(cls);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param individual
     * @return
     */
    private Set<OWLNamedIndividual> getPartsOfSameSpecies(OWLNamedIndividual individual) {
        if (!ontology.containsIndividualInSignature(individual.getIRI())) {
            return null;
        }

        Set<OWLClass> types = reasoner.getTypes(individual, true).getFlattened();
        if (Collections.disjoint(clsParts, types)) {
            return null;
        }

        Set<OWLNamedIndividual> values = reasoner.getObjectPropertyValues(individual, arePartsOf).getFlattened();
        if (values == null || values.size() != 1) {
            return null;
        }

        OWLNamedIndividual species = values.iterator().next();
        return this.getParts(species);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param species
     * @return
     */
    public Set<OWLNamedIndividual> getParts(OWLNamedIndividual species) {
        HashSet<OWLNamedIndividual> individuals = new HashSet<>();

        for (OWLClass cls : clsParts) {
            for (OWLIndividual i : cls.getIndividuals(ontology)) {
                OWLNamedIndividual part = i.asOWLNamedIndividual();

                if (!reasoner.getObjectPropertyValues(part, arePartsOf).containsEntity(species)) {
                    continue;
                }

                individuals.add(part);
            }
        }

        return individuals;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the structural reasoner does not do inferences, it just uses the asserted axioms in the ontology. In this case, this is probably what you needed anyway, but for other queries the results obtained with this code might be incomplete.

Comment: @Ignazio: Well, my intention was to use the asserted axioms in the ontology. According to what pointed out in your comment, I suppose that in other cases (ie: queries that require inferences) I should use a different reasoner. Is it exact?

Comment: Yes - I mentioned it because it has happened multiple times that developers have used this reasoner by mistake.